# Change setting in user control 's configuration file has no effect

Tags: c#, configuration, user-controls, configuration-files

I have a problem: change setting in user control's configuration file has no effect.

I can add "setting" to a user control project and can make following code work:

> label1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.DisplayName;

The output of this usercontrol project is "usercontorl1.dll" and "usercontrol1.dll.config".

When I test it in other project, I found that change the value in config file has no effect to its display. And even if there is no config file, it works fine!

How can I solve this problem , I really need a configurable user control.

Thank you.

Windows 7 64 bits
VS 2008
.Net 3.5

Ref:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/msbuild/thread/cbbd893c-8d5d-4699-bf51-bdd110946c94

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505252/winform-store-configuration-data-for-user-control

[Writing/Reading User-Defined settings in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083280/writing-reading-user-defined-settings-in-app-config-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy the config section to the App.Config of the using project.

The (only) file used at runtime is `AppName.exe.config`

Answer (score 2):

> When I test it in other project, I found that change the value in
>   config file has no effect to its display. And even if there is no
>   config file, it works fine!

Add the configuration of the user control in the "other project" i.e. the driving project.
ConfigurationManager class visualizes things in the current AppDomain and since your user control loads in the driving application's App Domain, the ConfigurationManager code would refer to the App.Config of the current AppDomain.
I believe that should help!
regds,

Comment: I believe Henk Holterman has already stated that!
I am sorry I did not see his answer.